# a complete and an incomplete metric space be homeomorphic

Tags: metric-spaces, continuous-homomorphisms

I wonder how to find such an example in the title. I already know that since it is a bijection, I have to choose different metrics anyway. but I do not know how to go on. Is it about a metric induced by a norm and the other not, or something else.

Comment: the metrics can not be equivalent right? otherwise one cauchy implies the other and can easily find the limit

Comment: $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ with the usual metric on both.